# Jquery $(this), .children, .siblings and etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to figure out which is the best method for sending data from a get request to a div. The issue that confuses me is to send it only to a div that is relative to the one calling the action. So when I click on the message_tab I want to send the data from the get request to the thread_load. however the thread_load is not a direct descendant of the message_tab yet a sibling to the message_flyout. How can i get this to send the data only to the sibling's thread_load? Here is what i have:

The message_tab and message_flyout are both a part of the appended message_block.

**HTML**

```
var el = $(
            '<div class = "message_block">'+
                '<div class = "message_tab" value = '+ user_id +' >'+ '</div>' +

                '<div class = "message_flyout">' +
                    '<div class = "message_content">' +
                        '<div class = "message_header">'+ '</div>' +
                            '<div class = "conversation_scroll">' +
                                '<div class = "scroll_content">' +
                                    '<ul class = "thread_load">'+ '</ul>'+
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                                    '<div class = "message_form">' +
                                        "<form class = 'myForm' action='"+'http://localhost:8000/newMsg/'+user_id+"' method= 'POST' accept-charset= 'UTF-8'>" + "<input name='_token' type='hidden' value='lbaqsTEePfIMYguGnsMvEDt8ExHly3dLKHtAu18c'>" +
                                        '<div class = "message_form">' +
                                            "<input class='input-mini' placeholder='Type a message...' name='body' type='text'>" +
                                        '</div>'+
                                        "</form>" +
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                    '</div>');
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $(document).on('click', '.message_tab', function(){
    var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
        var elem_data = $(this).siblings('.message_flyout');
            var data_transfer = $(elem_data).children('.thread_load');
    console.log(data_transfer);
    base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/thread';
        $.get(base_url + '/' + user_id , function (data) {
            $(data_transfer).closest('.thread_load').html(data);
        });
        $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
    $(this).parent('.message_block').css('width', '258px');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.message_tab', function () {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
    var elem_data = $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').find('.thread_load');
    console.log(data_transfer);
    base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/thread';
    $.get(base_url + '/' + user_id, function (data) {
        elem_data.html(data);
    });
    $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
    $(this).parent('.message_block').css('width', '258px');
});
```

`.closest` traverse upwards and return the first matching element. Whereas, `.find` traverse inside the node giving all the matching element.

**Note:**

And you should not use `value` as an attribute for a `div`, it is not valid thingy. Always use `data-whatever` and fetch it using either `.data('whatever')` or `.attr('data-whatever')`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$(document).on('click', '.message_tab', function(){

    var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
    var data_transfer = $(elem_data).children('.thread_load');
    var base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/thread';

    // Target thread load here
    var $thread_load =  $(this).next('.message_flyout').find('ul.thread_load');

    $.get(base_url + '/' + user_id , function (data) {
        $thread_load.html(data);
    });

    $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
    $(this).parent('.message_block').css('width', '258px');
});
```

.message flyout comes directly after .message_tab, so if we move to that element then use .find which is the fastest way to retrieve thread load you should be good. I haven't tested this however.